# Version Syntax Explanation?

Tags: version-control

I've seen a common, I guess you could say naming convention, for version names. Ex. 1.0.3

It is my understanding that it is {main}.{major}.{minor}. Does anyone know of some good articles that explain what each of those consists of? Or perhaps could just shed some light on it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled it for you:  I typed 'versioning' and first link I got was:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning

[HTH](http://www.acronymfinder.com/HTH.html)

BTW - there is no syntax.  If you are producing a software, adopt any scheme that feels logical to you.  You can always have your versioning upgraded if something will feel more right to you at later time.

Don't forget to upgrade versioning version also :)

Comment: Well don't i look silly, Thank you. Just what i was looking for.

Comment: Time has moved on.  7 years later we have this: https://semver.org/

Answer (score 1):

Every organization makes up their own meanings for version numbers.  You have to check their documentation if you want to be sure what they mean as far as compatibility and such.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly versioning is subjective based on the conventions a person/project decides to use.

Typically though, it is related to release cycles, bug fixes and new features being implemented.

A related SO question provides a [good explanation regarding what the assembly numbering means](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279235/268667) (The detail is in the question, not the answer)